# Not able to delete second generation unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, second-generation-packaging, sf

I have accidentally created two packages and I want to delete one of them. I tried the below command.

`sf package delete --package "my-pckg" --target-dev-hub my-dev`

But it results into the below error.

> Error (1): Can’t delete the package or package version because you
> don’t have sufficient user permissions. To delete packages or package
> versions, the Delete Second-Generation Packages user permission must
> be enabled.

Upon investigating further I found that there is permission for this - **Delete Second-Generation Packages (Delete packages and package versions)**.

I created a permission set with this permission and tried assigning it to my user (from dev hub org).

But now I can't assign this Permission Set to my user. Here is the error I ran into.

> Failure : Can't assign permission set Package Delete to user Rahul
> Gawale. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Delete packages and package versions.

[image]

My user license is Salesforce and is a Salesforce Admin. I wonder what license type is required to do this?

> Please note that I am using a developer edition org.

Answer (score 3):

'Delete Second-Generation Packages' can work OK with the following:

User:

- License: **Salesforce Limited Access - Free**
- Profile: **Limited Access User**

Permission Set:

- User License: **Salesforce Limited Access - Free**

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, in my developer edition org, there is no license "Salesforce Limited Acess - Free". It seems like it is not available for developer edition orgs according to this article [Determine Which License to Assign to Dev Hub Users
](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/dev_hub_license.htm)?